# Locate DLL path by giving a DLLName

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll

If I do

```
LoadLibrary("MyTest.dll")
```

Windows will locate and load it from `"C:\TestFolder\Test\MyTest.dll"`, because `"C:\TestFolder\Test\"` is in `%PATH%` folder.

How can I emulate same function? I need to locate `C:\TestFolder\Test\MyTest.dll` (`C:\TestFolder\Test\` is in `%PATH%`) by passing `MyTest.dll` as an argument to a function. Is there such an API? or a function?

P.S. I can't do LoadLibrary and then GetModuleHandle and finding Path, sometimes this DLL could be malicious DLL and I can't load it. So I need to find PATH without having to load it.

Comment: How is this going to prevent you from loading a malicious DLL? Even if you do this, you'll eventually need to load the DLL, in which case you're right back where you started from.

Comment: @user3404070 Is your DLL so popular that persons will make malicious versions of it?

Comment: Use ***[GetModuleFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***.

Comment: @ryyker, GetModuleFileName need DLL to be loaded in memory which I don't want to do.

Comment: Is your question how to write a function that takes a filename as input, examines `%PATH%` and looks if a file with that name exists in some path, returning the filename?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, please re-read the question, your comment is off-topic.

Comment: @mafso, EXACTLY! and as windows already does this always, I thought maybe there is an API for it that I missed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To load the DLL without running any malicious code inside, use `LoadLibraryEx` with the `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` and `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flags.

Then you can use `GetModuleFileName`.

You should also read about all the other flags, which allow you to perform all the various searches Windows is capable of.

Comment: Indeed that works in this case. A more general solution would be [`PathFindOnPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773594.aspx).

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you both! I think PathFindOnPath is safer, isn't it?

Comment: @Cody: Not really.  Constructing the value of the `ppszOtherDirs` argument that requires is not easy, and might need to change in future Windows versions.

Comment: No, you don't need to specify anything there. He just wants to look on the system path, it does that if you pass `NULL` for the second parameter.

Comment: @CodyGray: Did you even read the comments on the `PathFindOnPath` MSDN page?  It does not use the DLL search order.

Comment: Yes, ppszOtherDirs simply could be current running app dir or empty, PathFindOnPath worked exactly as I wanted! Thank you Cody Gray!

Comment: Well, no, I didn't read the comments. They are usually noise. I just read the documentation, which confirms that it searches folders in the PATH environment variable. It sounds to me like that's what he is wanting. I've read the comments now, and they say that it doesn't search the current directory. The documentation doesn't confirm or deny that, so I'll assume it's correct. And you're right, that's different from the behavior of `LoadLibrary[Ex]`. But that's not what I read the question as asking for.

Comment: @CodyGray: And that still doesn't account for the `KnownDlls` registry entries.  If he wants the path to the DLL his first code snippet will load, he needs to use the real DLL search logic.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I already said that LoadLibraryEx would be a better solution for DLLs. I just suggested the shell helper function as a more general solution. Perhaps we have a different understanding of the question. I'm basing mine largely on an affirmative response to [mafso's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463881/locate-dll-path-by-giving-a-dllname/25463956?noredirect=1#comment39736127_25463881).

Comment: So wait, what's exactly difference of LoadLibraryEx and PathFindOnPath? Would PathFindOnPath do the job?

Comment: The difference, @user, is that there are [special rules used for locating DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx). The LoadLibrary functions take those rules into account, and are therefore the most appropriate choice in this case. The PathFindOnPath function *only* searches (if you pass NULL for the second parameter) in the folders on the system PATH, which is *one* of the places Windows searches for DLLs, but not the *only* place. As such, if you call PathFindOnPath, you might get a different DLL file than the one you'd get if you tried to load it.

Comment: @CodyGray, Thank you! Totally understood. Thank you Ben Voigt! I was aware of LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE, also I was aware of LoadLibrary GetModuleFilname, but never thought using them together is the solution for my problem! I just learned a very good point.

Comment: @CodyGray - Your original comment adds real value to the discussion.  It can be generally applied in many ways even beyond the scope of this post.  Would you consider posting it (with comment) as an answer?

Comment: @ryyker PathFindOnPath does not do the DLL search. Ben's answer is the right answer.

Comment: @rua.kr: *What* is not working?  You get an error from `LoadLibraryEx` with the specified flags?  You get an error from `GetModuleFileName`?  You get a valid path from `GetModuleFileName` but it is the path of the wrong copy of the DLL?  You tried something different from my answer's instructions, and that something different is failing?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to this question will not work in all scenarios. More specifically, using `GetModuleFileName` together with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` will only work if the library was already loaded prior without this flag. For example, it will work for a library like KERNEL32.DLL which is already loaded by the process, but it will not work with your own library being loaded into the process for the first time.

This is because, to quote The Old New Thing, [a library loaded via LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE (or similar flags) doesn't get to play in any reindeer module games.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141120-00/?p=43573)

> If you load a library with the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATA­FILE flag, then it
> isn’t really loaded in any normal sense. In fact, it’s kept completely
> off the books. If you load a library with the
> LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATA­FILE, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATA­FILE_EXCLUSIVE, or
> LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE flag (or any similar flag added in the
> future), then the library gets mapped into the process address space,
> but it is not a true module. Functions like Get­Module­Handle,
> Get­Module­File­Name, Enum­Process­Modules and
> Create­Toolhelp32­Snapshot will not see the library, because it was
> never entered into the database of loaded modules.

At that point, you might as well just use `GetModuleHandle`, since it'll only work with previously loaded libraries. Obviously not ideal, and doesn't actually answer the question of getting the path without executing DllMain.

What about the other flag, `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES`? Well, technically yes it will work. However, you'll notice in the Microsoft documentation the following note.

> Do not use this value; it is provided only for backward compatibility.
> If you are planning to access only data or resources in the DLL, use
> LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE
> or both.

The flag is only provided for backwards compatibility, and that is for good reason. To quote The Old New Thing a second time, [DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES is a time bomb.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050214-00/?p=36463)

> It is common for somebody to call GetModuleHandle to see if a DLL is
> loaded, and if so, use GetProcAddress to get a procedure address and
> call it. If the DLL had been loaded with DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES,
> both the GetModuleHandle will succeed, but the resulting function will
> crash when called. The code doing this has no idea that the DLL was
> loaded with DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES; it has no way of protecting
> itself.

Other threads will see the library is loaded. If they attempt to use the loaded library, as would be entirely normal to do, they will crash the program because it has not actually been initialized. So this flag, while it does work with `GetModuleFileName`, will cause instability in the program. Still not ideal.

So then, if we can't use `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` or `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` with `GetModuleFileName`, then what is the solution? Well, the solution is to not use `GetModuleFileName` - and instead use `GetMappedFileName`.

At this point, if you know what `GetMappedFileName` does, you may be confused. Normally, `GetMappedFileName` is used to get a filename from a File Mapping, created with the [File Mapping API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping). Well, the secret is that under the hood, image loading is accomplished with `MapViewOfFile`. This is subtly hinted at by the Dbghelp documentation - for example, the [ImageNtHeader documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-imagentheader) which states an image base must be...

> The base address of an image that is mapped into memory by a call to
> the MapViewOfFile function.

This means that not only is a module handle a pointer to a module, but also a mapped file pointer. Unlike `GetModuleFileName` however, `GetMappedFileName` has no concept of "the reindeer module games," so it works even with the `LOAD_LIBARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag of `LoadLibraryEx`. Not only that, but `GetMappedFileName` has an additional benefit over `GetModuleFileName`.

Something you might not know is that simply loading a library with LoadLibrary does not exclusively lock the DLL file. Try it yourself: write a simple program which loads your own library with `LoadLibrary`, and then while the program is running, cut and paste the DLL file to a different location. This will work (and yes, has always worked regardless of Windows version) so long as no other application has a lock on the DLL file. The File Mapping API just keeps on chugging, regardless of the DLL file's new location.

However, when you call `GetModuleFileName`, it will always return the path of the DLL file **as of whenever the library was loaded with LoadLibrary.** This has security ramifications. It would be possible to cut and paste the DLL file to a new location, and put a different one at the old location. If the path returned by `GetModuleFileName` is used to load the library again, it could actually result in loading a different DLL file altogether. As such, `GetModuleFileName` is only useful for the purpose of displaying the name or getting the DLL file name passed to `LoadLibrary`, and can't be depended upon for the current file path.

`GetMappedFileName` has no such issue, because it has no concept of when `LoadLibrary` was called. It returns an up to date path to the file, even if it has been moved while it's loaded.

There is one minor downside though: `GetMappedFileName` returns a device path, in the format of `\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Example.DLL`. Thankfully, it's a resolvable issue. We can use `QueryDosDevice` to turn the device path into a drive path.

```
bool getFilePathNameFromMappedView(HANDLE process, LPVOID mappedView, std::string &filePathName) {
    if (!process) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!mappedView) {
        return false;
    }

    CHAR mappedFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";

    if (!GetMappedFileName(process, mappedView, mappedFileName, MAX_PATH - 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    // the mapped file name is a device path, we need a drive path
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/defining-an-ms-dos-device-name
    const SIZE_T DEVICE_NAME_SIZE = 3;
    CHAR deviceName[DEVICE_NAME_SIZE] = "A:";

    // the additional character is for the trailing slash we add
    size_t targetPathLength = 0;
    CHAR targetPath[MAX_PATH + 1] = "";

    // find the MS-DOS Device Name
    DWORD logicalDrives = GetLogicalDrives();

    do {
        if (logicalDrives & 1) {
            if (!QueryDosDevice(deviceName, targetPath, MAX_PATH - 1)) {
                return false;
            }

            // add a trailing slash
            targetPathLength = strnlen_s(targetPath, MAX_PATH);
            targetPath[targetPathLength++] = '\\';

            // compare the Target Path to the Device Object Name in the Mapped File Name
            // case insensitive
            // https://flylib.com/books/en/4.168.1.23/1/
            if (!_strnicmp(targetPath, mappedFileName, targetPathLength)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        deviceName[0]++;
    } while (logicalDrives >>= 1);

    if (!logicalDrives) {
        return false;
    }

    // get the drive path
    filePathName = std::string(deviceName) + "\\" + (mappedFileName + targetPathLength);
    return true;
}
```

`GetLogicalDrives` just gets a list of which drives are available (like C:, D:, etc.) in the form of a bitmask (where the first bit corresponds to A:, the second bit corresponds to B:, etc.) We then loop through the available drives, getting their paths, and comparing them against the one in the Mapped File Name. The result of this function is a path that could be passed to the `CreateFile` function.

The only source I could find for whether these device paths are case-insensitive or not was [this book](https://flylib.com/books/en/4.168.1.23/1/) claiming that they used to be case-sensitive, but are case-insensitive as of Windows XP. I'm going to assume you are not targeting Windows 9x anymore, so I just compare them case-insensitively.

**Edit:** I only realized much later after writing this that there is a much better way to write this function. By simply prepending the path with the prefix "\\?\GLOBALROOT" the file can be opened directly by `CreateFile` without going through `QueryDosDevice`. As far as I can tell, this has [always worked since Windows NT,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#nt-namespaces) so there is no disadvantage to doing it this way instead, but I left my original implementation for context. Here is the simpler implementation of `getFilePathNameFromMappedView`.

```
bool getFilePathNameFromMappedView(HANDLE process, LPVOID mappedView, std::string &filePathName) {
    if (!process) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!mappedView) {
        return false;
    }

    CHAR mappedFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";

    if (!GetMappedFileName(process, mappedView, mappedFileName, MAX_PATH - 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    filePathName = "\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT" + std::string(mappedFileName);
    return true;
}
```

**Hold on a second though:** this still may not be enough. If your intention is, as mine was, to try and get a *file handle* to the DLL file, but using the DLL search path, then just getting the path and passing it to `CreateFile` opens us up to a *filesystem race condition,* like the kind explained in [this LiveOverflow video.](https://youtu.be/5g137gsB9Wk) A technique like this could be abused by a hacker so the handle doesn't actually point to the file we want. There isn't any `GetMappedFileHandle` function, so what can we do?

I thought about this for a while, and here is the workaround I came up with. The idea is that we call our own `getFilePathNameFromMappedView` function once just to get the path to pass to `CreateFile`, and exclusively lock the file in place with the `FILE_SHARE_READ` flag. However, we then confirm, with a second call to `getFilePathNameFromMappedView`, that the file is still actually there. If the paths match, knowing that the file at that path is now locked, we can know for sure the handle we got is to the library that was actually loaded. If the file was moved before the call to `CreateFile` finished, however, the paths will not match, because `GetMappedFileName` returns the up to date path to the file. At that point, we can try again. I'm using [scope_guard](https://github.com/Neargye/scope_guard) in order to ensure the handle is closed upon failure.

```
inline bool stringEqualsCaseInsensitive(const char* str, const char* str2) {
    return !_stricmp(str, str2);
}

inline bool closeHandle(HANDLE &handle) {
    if (handle && handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (!CloseHandle(handle)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    handle = NULL;
    return true;
}

bool getHandleFromModuleHandle(HMODULE moduleHandle, HANDLE &file) {
    if (!moduleHandle) {
        return false;
    }

    bool result = true;

    HANDLE currentProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    std::string filePathName = "";
    std::string filePathName2 = "";

    const int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
        // pass the Module Handle as a Mapped View
        // to get its current path
        if (!getFilePathNameFromMappedView(currentProcess, moduleHandle, filePathName)) {
            return false;
        }

        {
            // prevent the Example File from being written to, moved, renamed, or deleted
            // by acquiring it and effectively locking it from other processes
            file = CreateFile(filePathName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

            if (!file || file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                return false;
            }

            MAKE_SCOPE_EXIT(fileCloseHandleScopeExit) {
                if (!closeHandle(file)) {
                    result = false;
                }
            };

            // we now know this path is now protected against race conditions
            // but the path may have changed before we acquired it
            // so ensure the File Path Name is the same as before
            // so that we know the path we protected is for the Mapped View
            if (!getFilePathNameFromMappedView(currentProcess, moduleHandle, filePathName2)) {
                return false;
            }

            if (stringEqualsCaseInsensitive(filePathName.c_str(), filePathName2.c_str())) {
                fileCloseHandleScopeExit.dismiss();
                return result;
            }
        }

        // if an error occured, return
        if (!result) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then we can call it like this...

```
HMODULE exampleModuleHandle = LoadLibraryEx("Example.DLL", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);

if (!exampleModuleHandle) {
    return false;
}

// we want this to be a handle to the Example File
HANDLE exampleFile = NULL;

if (!getHandleFromModuleHandle(exampleModuleHandle, exampleFile)) {
    return false;
}
```

This is just something I thought of, so let me know in the responses if there are issues with it.

Once you have a handle to the file, it can then be passed to `GetFileInformationByHandle` to confirm it is the same library as is loaded in another process, and subsequently closed with `CloseHandle`.