# Using Pefile in Python to find absolute paths for an executable's DLLs

Tags: python, winapi, reverse-engineering

I am attempting to use the Python pefile to extract .text and do some disassembling. I have been successful in that regard. I also want to be able to do the same with all DLLs associated with the binary image. I have not been able to figure out how to do this, and I am not sure if that is possible with pefile.

I can use pefile to enumerate all DLLs that are imported by an executable. That is easy to do and not an issue. How can I then use Python or pefile to find the absolute path for DLLs, so that I can then extract .text from each of those DLLs?

One approach I have looked at was to simply find the absolute path for all DLLs. I have searched extensively and not found a way to do that within Python. If I can find the absolute path, i.e. file location, then I can then go and extract the .text section?

Another possibility could be to create a process, and try to get DLL location that way. This could be done possibly by using GetModuleHandleW from kernel32, which could be used with win32api. I would like to AVOID this solution if at all possible. It needs to become a process first in order to do this function. Even if I were to do this, the parameter for that function requires a handle, and I am not sure how to get it DLLs in the form of handles. But again, I would like to avoid having the executable become a process. If someone has a suggestion on how to make this work, that would be great, although I prefer not to, as I wish to not have an executable become an active process.

Another possibility that I have concerned but not looked at is having pefile enumerate all the DLLs and then search the harddisk for them. This could be inaccurate though as there could be multiple DLLs of the same name and it would take too long to go search for all of them.

I recognize that ASLR will come into play with many DLLs. I am not concerned with this, as I am only looking for offsets. I am only considering well-formed, non-malicious PEs here. I can only consider Python solutions.

I am hoping for an elegant way to somehow be able to do this, either by being able to find the file location / absolute pathname for all DLLs or find a way using Pefile to somehow be able to extract the .text from an executable's imported DLLs without needing to supply it with the file location for each of the DLLs.

Answer (score 2):

A PE file does not contain information about absolute paths of the modules it needs and there is no way to parse that out of the PE file. What you can do is emulate the way the OS finds these files with `LoadLibraryEx` (passing the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag [will load the module without running any code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25463956/4454124)) and then pass these paths over to pefile.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did use loadlibraryex with win32api to load it and obtain the necessary path to pass over to pefile, and it did work as described. Doing a search on some of those will help turn up some sample codes, i.e. loadlibraryex with win32api, win32con and pefile. I was fairly certain that info wasn't in the PE file, but wonder if it might be able to be derived in some roundabout, indirect fashion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As @mnistic suggested LoadLibraryEX with a load as data flag set will work, if you want to explicitly calculate the paths and examine the on-disk file then you should See [DLL Search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

under this pay attention to the section **Standard Search Order for Desktop Applications**

Primarily you have to emulate what the `ldr` is doing.

Comment: So what happens if I have something like ntdll and ntdll, one which is 32 bit and one which is 64 bit. If my target application is 32 bit, of course I want the 32-bit one. How can I tell it that I want 64 bit using Python win32api or similar? Right now I am dealing just with 32 bit, but would like to expand and also deal with 64 bit. If the content of the .text section differs in any way, any differences whatsoever, then I would need the 64 bit. I am not concerned with loading order, just loading the *right* one. For my current needs, which is 32 bit, it addresses it.

Comment: for 32bit process on 64bit machine except for WOW64*.dll and ntdll.dll(64 bit) all other DLLs are 32 bit DLL. The magic number for the image pe format is 0x10b for PE32 andIMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC:0x20b for PE64