# winapi - find DLL path from file name

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to get DLL path from DLL filename

like

```cpp
FindDll("in_exe_dir.dll") == "path/to/exe/exe_dir.dll"
FindDll("in_working_dir.dll") == "path/to/working/dir/in_working_dir.dll"
FindDll("in_dll_dir.dll") == "path/to/dll/dir/in_dll_dir.dll"
FindDll("in_system_dir.dll") == "path/to/system/dir/in_system_dir.dll"
```

Is there any `FindDll`-Like function?

LoadLibrary, but return file path instead of the handle without loading

Comment: [`GetModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea)?

Comment: That assumes that the module is already loaded, though. FWIW, I recall having had a need similar to what the OP is asking for: "tell me which dll you'll be loading, but don't load it", but I am not aware of a way to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locate DLL path by giving a DLLName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463881/locate-dll-path-by-giving-a-dllname)

Comment: @dewaffled Right! Thanks!

Comment: @dewaffled but not working on unloaded DLL

Comment: @rua.kr You said that in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463881/), too. But you haven't provided ANY details about WHAT is not working exactly. Please be more specific.

Comment: Right now this is very much an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): You tell us your wanted solution, but you don't tell us the problem it's supposed to solve. Why do you need this? And why can't you (even temporarily) load the DLL to get the path? Perhaps if you asked about the actual problem directly instead, giving this "find dll function" as a possible solution, and we might be able to help you with the real problem instead.

Comment: I just want to find and report the missing one. and I just checked all DLL paths manually with these rule https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order